# PowerShell script(s) run separately but not together, cant figure out why

Tags: powershell, scripting, acl

I have a couple of PS scripts which I'm trying to combine into one but its not working. I have one script to copy a folder structure using robocopy, then copy some additional files into the newly created folder structure. The second script copies the acls from the source to the destination.

If I run the robocopy script then the copy acl script separately it works fine, but when I combine them the acls do not get copied...

Robocopy Script:

```powershell
## Asks User which Purpose they would like to clone
$ReadHostSourceFolder = "c:\sp6" #Read-Host "Enter the full path of the Source Folder without the final \"

## Asks User where they would like the clone to be copied to 
$ReadHostTargetFolder = "c:\SP7" #Read-Host "Enter the full path of the desired Destination without the final \"

## Sets arrays for additional files to be copied
$RPackSFolder = $ReadHostSourceFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Run Packagers"
$RPackTFolder = $ReadHostTargetFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Run Packagers"
$RViewerSFolder = $ReadHostSourceFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Results Viewers\"
$RViewerTFolder = $ReadHostTargetFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Results Viewers\"
$DPackSFolder = $ReadHostSourceFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Data Packagers\"
$DPackTFolder = $ReadHostTargetFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\Data Packagers\"
$LHSSFolder = $ReadHostSourceFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\LHS ETL Tool\"
$LHSTFolder = $ReadHostTargetFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\End User Apps\LHS ETL Tool\"
$ModelsSFolder = $ReadHostSourceFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\Aggregation Kernel Build\Models"
$ModelsTFolder = $ReadHostTargetFolder + "\Aggregation Kernel\Aggregation Kernel Build\Models"

## Clones just the folder structure from the Source to the Target destination
robocopy $ReadHostSourceFolder $ReadHostTargetFolder /e /xf *.*

## Copies additional files to the new purpose
Copy-Item -Path $RPackSFolder\*.* -Destination $RPackTFolder  
Copy-Item -Path $RViewerSFolder\*.* -Destination $RViewerTFolder  
Copy-Item -Path $DPackSFolder\*.* -Destination $DPackTFolder  
Copy-Item -Path $LHSSFolder\*.* -Destination $LHSTFolder
```

And here is the copy acl script:

```powershell
$ReadHostSourceFolder = "C:\SP6"  
$ReadHostTargetFolder = "C:\SP7"  

$TFolders = GCI $ReadHostTargetFolder -Recurse | Select -ExpandProperty Fullname  

GCI -LiteralPath $ReadHostSourceFolder -Recurse | % {  
    $SPath = $_.FullName  
    $TPath = $_.FullName -replace     "$($ReadHostSourceFolder.replace("\","\\"))","$ReadHostTargetFolder"  
    $NewACL = Get-Acl -LiteralPath $SPath  
    $NewACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)  
    If ($TFolders -ccontains $TPath){  
        Try{          
        Set-Acl -LiteralPath $TPath -AclObject $NewACL -EA Stop  
        Echo "Copied permission from $SPath to $TPath"  
        }Catch{  
        Echo "Error on copying permission from $SPath to $TPath : $($_.Exception.Message)"  
        }  
    } Else{  
    Echo "Unable to find destination for $SPath"  
    }  
}
```

Obviously I'm removing the repeated `$ReadHostSourceFolder` and `$ReadHostTargetFolder` from the copy acl script once its combined.

I’m stumped so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Found some additional info, if I set `$ReadHostTargetFolder` to c:\SP7 it doesn't work, but if I set it to C:\SP7 (with capital C:) it does work...Doesn't seem to matter what case I set `$ReadHostSourceFolder` to or even what case I use after C:\ in `$ReadHostTargetFolder` e.g. C:\sp7 works just as well as C:\SP7 whereas c:\SP7 or c:\sp7 will not.

I suspect its due to this line `"$($ReadHostSourceFolder.replace("\","\\"))","$ReadHostTargetFolder"` making it go all case sensitive, not sure why though?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't simply let `robocopy` sync the permissions (`robocopy /sec`)?

Comment: I wanted to remove inheritance as well `$NewACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)` pretty sure robocopy just copies the source and you cant manipulate it at all...

Comment: Do you actually want to set explicit permissions on all files/folders? I wouldn't recommend that, because it usually becomes a pain in the rear. If anything I'd copy permissions from the source (root) folder to the destination (root) folder, and leave the rest to `robocopy`.

Comment: Yeah i need to set specific permissions on certain files and folders. There are some folders in further in the structure where users will have different permissions i.e. the `$LHSSFolder` is write access where as others in this tree are not

Comment: So set permissions on the root folder, run `robocopy`, then fix permissions in the destination as needed after `robocopy` finishes. However, explicit ACLs in the source should already have been copied over when using the option `/sec`.